# Is large swap appropriate for infrequent, high memory task?

Tags: ram, swap

Hypothetical:
I have a workstation with 32 GB RAM which is perfectly fine for most tasks. However, I rarely (1-2 times/year) need to perform a task that is very, very memory intensive (i.e. 150 GB Memory needed). Its fine for this to take a long time since its infrequent. Would it be appropriate to buy a 1TB SSD and dedicate it to Swap instead of upgrading to 256 GB RAM given the price difference? Would this even work?

For a bit more information, the large task involves large scale genomic data and most of the memory is taken in the form of very large hash tables, if I understand the software correctly.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema, This is not a real machine. Purely a hypothetical question to better understand the interaction between Swap and RAM

Comment: Then no, it would not be appropriate to have a 1TB SSD be swap in this hypo example.

Comment: @heynnema, could you explain why so I can better understand? What would you expect to go wrong in this system?

Comment: It would be more appropriate to try tuning the system, starting with an appropriate /swapfile and adjusting vm.swappiness, for a start. Prefer not to use SSD for a swap. But since this is hypo, it's kind of moot, isn't it?